# maximum recursion depth on stdout capture in logging

Tags: python, logging, recursion, jenkins

I have my logger configured as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging
import logging.handlers
import sys
import os
import re


class MaskFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, fmt, masks):
        logging.Formatter.__init__(self, fmt)
        self.masks = masks

    def format(self, record):
        result = logging.Formatter.format(self, record)
        if result is not None:
            result = self.masks.sub("*" * 25, result)
        return result


class LoggerWriter:
    def __init__(self, level):
        # self.level is really like using log.debug(message)
        # at least in my case
        self.level = level

    def write(self, message):
        # if statement reduces the amount of newlines that are
        # printed to the logger
        if message != '\n':
            self.level("stdout: " + message)

    def flush(self):
        # create a flush method so things can be flushed when
        # the system wants to. Not sure if simply 'printing'
        # sys.stderr is the correct way to do it, but it seemed
        # to work properly for me.
        self.level("stderr: " + sys.stderr)


VERBOSE = 5

log = logging.getLogger("my_logger")

logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger("selenium").setLevel(logging.INFO)

logging.addLevelName(5, "VERBOSE")

masks_compile = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, ["some_pass_1", "some_pass_2"])))

c_formatter = MaskFormatter('%(message)s', masks_compile)
f_formatter = MaskFormatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s: \t %(message)s', masks_compile)

f_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "tests.log"), mode='a', maxBytes=3000000, backupCount=10)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_formatter)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

c_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
c_handler.setFormatter(c_formatter)
c_handler.setLevel(int(os.environ.get("logging_level", "5")))

log.addHandler(c_handler)
log.addHandler(f_handler)
log.setLevel(int(os.environ.get("logging_level", "5")))


sys.stdout = LoggerWriter(log.debug)
sys.stderr = LoggerWriter(log.warning)
```

Notice im capturing stdout and stderr.

The problem that I'm encountering randomly, while running on Jenkins, is, that on logging simple message, logger goes into maximum recursion. Tests fail differently, but each one goes into such recursion in line "self.level("stdout: " + message)"

One of the stack-traces:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 384, in doCleanups
        function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\jenkins\workspace\PLC_Tests_Core_Functionalities_Win7_64b_Nightly\automation\tests\ds_setup.py", line 191, in failedReset
        log.info("Test failed, will reinstall DS and set subscribed to initial ones")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1160, in info
        self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1279, in _log
        self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1289, in handle
        self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1329, in callHandlers
        hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 757, in handle
        self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 82, in emit
        self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 810, in handleError
        None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
        _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
        file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\jenkins\workspace\PLC_Tests_Core_Functionalities_Win7_64b_Nightly\automation\pages\log.py", line 36, in write
        self.level("stdout: " + message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1172, in warning
        self._log(WARNING, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1279, in _log
        self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1289, in handle
        self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1329, in callHandlers
        hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 757, in handle
        self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 82, in emit
        self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 810, in handleError
        None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
        _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
        file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\jenkins\workspace\PLC_Tests_Core_Functionalities_Win7_64b_Nightly\automation\pages\log.py", line 36, in write
        self.level("stdout: " + message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1172, in warning
        self._log(WARNING, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1279, in _log
        self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1289, in handle
        self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1329, in callHandlers
        hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 757, in handle
        self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 82, in emit
        self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 810, in handleError
        None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
        _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
        file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\xunit.py", line 129, in write
        s.write(data)
```

I run the tests with:

```
nosetests -v -s --with-xunit --xunit-file=path/to/xml path/to/tests --with-allure --logdir=path/to/output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the issue comes from attempting to both read and write from the same stream (stdout). So I assume Your intent is to capture all stdout/stderr messages created by the application (like logging from 3rd party modules). In this case it's best to configure all loggers to propagate the messages to parent loggers, and adding a root logger which logs the data in a manner You choose.

If the logging structure is complex, I recommend using [logging_tree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logging_tree) to discover:

```
import logging_tree
import nose
logging_tree.printout()
...
```

So we get the logger **o<--"nose"
       Level NOTSET so inherits level WARNING**

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("nose").propagate = True
logging.getLogger().addHandler(<Your handler>)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Now anytime nose logs anything,  will also receive this message. I recommend [Python Advanced Logging Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial) , can be helpful when dealing with large projects.

Comment: yeah, exactly - my intention is to capture stuff from other modules; what you proposed seems more reasonable. Accepted as answer.